# Set utf8 to mysql connection with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, utf-8

I have a big problem here. Many rows of my mysql table got accent on data and when I get these information using a javascript it return FATAL ERROR 200. I want to know if I can get all data in UTF8 and set it on MySQL Connection.
This is my connection file

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
class dbconfig {
    protected static $host = "";
    protected static $username = "";
    protected static $password = "";
    protected static $dbname = "";
    static $con;

    function __construct() {
        self::$con = self::connect(); 
    }

    protected static function connect() {
        try {
            $link = mysqli_connect(self::$host, self::$username, self::$password, self::$dbname); 
            if(!$link) {
                throw new exception(mysqli_error($link));
            }
            return $link;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "Error: ".$e->getMessage();
        } 
    }

    public static function close() {
        mysqli_close(self::$con);
    }

    public static function run($query) {
        try {
            if(empty($query) && !isset($query)) {
                throw new exception("Query string is not set.");
            }
            $result = mysqli_query(self::$con, $query);
            self::close();
            return $result;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "Error: ".$e->getMessage();
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Unless I am missing something, there is no PDO here...

Answer (score 0):

Solution

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
class dbconfig {
    protected static $host = "";
    protected static $username = "";
    protected static $password = "";
    protected static $dbname = "";
    static $con;

    function __construct() {
        self::$con = self::connect(); 
    }

    protected static function connect() {
        try {
            $link = mysqli_connect(self::$host, self::$username, self::$password, self::$dbname); 
            mysqli_set_charset($link,"utf8");
            if(!$link) {
                throw new exception(mysqli_error($link));
            }
            return $link;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "Error: ".$e->getMessage();
        } 
    }

    public static function close() {
        mysqli_close(self::$con);
    }

    public static function run($query) {
        try {
            if(empty($query) && !isset($query)) {
                throw new exception("Query string is not set.");
            }
            $result = mysqli_query(self::$con, $query);
            self::close();
            return $result;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "Error: ".$e->getMessage();
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: The key line is `mysqli_set_charset($link,"utf8");`.